# Ressource not found error in postman with spring

Tags: java, spring

i'm a beginner and i'm testing springboot, creating a simple api.
When testing my post request via postman, it gives me a 404 error.
[postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iS6n.png)

```
package com.ecommerce.microcommerce;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.ecommerce.microcommerce.repository")
public class MicrocommerceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MicrocommerceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

UserRepository :

```
package com.ecommerce.micocommerce.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.ecommerce.microcommerce.model.User;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    
}
```

UserService :

```
package com.ecommerce.microcommerce.service;

import java.util.List;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.ecommerce.micocommerce.repository.UserRepository;
import com.ecommerce.microcommerce.model.User;

@Service
@Transactional
public class UserService {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    
    public void saveUser(User user) {
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
```

UserController :

```
package com.ecommerce.microcommerce.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.ecommerce.microcommerce.model.User;
import com.ecommerce.microcommerce.service.UserService;

@RestController
public class UserController {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @PostMapping("/Users")
    public void addUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        System.out.println(user);
        userService.saveUser(user);
    }
}
```

application.properties :

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/microcommerce?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root


#Hibernate
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

I noticed that since I added the @ComponentScan annotation, postman returns me a 404.
But I have to use this one because otherwise @Autowired does not work.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `@ComponentScan` is not scanning your `Controller` neither your `Service`.
In fact, having it is not needed at all when using `@SpringBootApplication`. This should scan all packages that it's part of, in your case, `com.ecommerce.microcommerce`.

Perhaps your `Repository` has not been scanned/autowired because of a type on your package name?
`micocommerce` vs `microcommerce`.

---

tip: use constructor injection instead of autowiring

```java
@RestController
public class UserController {
    
    private final UserService userService;

    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    // methods
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit **@ComponentScan("com.ecommerce.microcommerce.repository")** to **@ComponentScan("com.ecommerce.microcommerce)** so that it scans Controller, Services and Repositories in your base package. Please check [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html) how Springboot uses @SpringBootApplication annotation(as it already enables @ComponentScan feature):

Please do check the package name(micocommerce) you have provided for the **UserRepository** class.